# What backup option shall I chose in the Nexus 7 toolkit to backup everything on my Nexus 7?

Tags: rooting, backup, nexus-7

The options are:

### BACKUP OPTIONS [ALL OPTIONS REQUIRE ADB MODE]

1. Backup ALL installed apps [-all]
2. Backup Individual Packages [a single app] ONLY
3. Backup your Internal Storage [virtual SD Card]
4. CWM  NANDROID Backup [boot, cache, data, recovery, system]
5. TWRP NANDROID Backup [boot, cache, data, recovery, system]       [coming soon]
6. Pull /data folder [excluding /data/media] ONLY to your PC
7. Pull /system folder ONLY to your PC
8. Dump selected Device Partitions to PC